# use Powershell substring and Regex to extract a variable number of tokens

Tags: regex, powershell, text-parsing

I got help from this forum to use Powershell and Regex below

```
if((get-content -Raw c:\config.txt) -match '(?ms)^999.*?(?=\r?\n\S|\Z)')
{ $matches[0]}
```

to successfully extract the correct info for vlan 999 unused from the config below

```
1    default                          active    Fa0/4, Fa0/5, Fa0/6, Fa0/7, Fa0/8
120  Camera                           active    Fa0/2
130  Student                  active    Fa0/1
100  Management                        active    
999  Unused               active    Fa0/10, Fa0/11, Fa0/12, Fa0/13, 
                                                Fa0/14, Fa0/15, Fa0/16, Fa0/17
                                                Fa0/18, Fa0/19
```

and then I was able to use the substring method below to extract just the ports number as

```
Fa0/10, Fa0/11, Fa0/12, Fa0/13, Fa0/14, Fa0/15, Fa0/16, Fa0/17 Fa0/18, Fa0/19

$Unused_VLAN = $Matches[0]
$Unused_ports = Unused_VLAN.substring (48, 77)
```

my problem is I have to extract this information on multiple config files and each config file has different number of unused ports.

My question is there a better way than to use substring method to extract the unused ports because I have to specify the exact starting position and the ending position of the string to extract the ports so other config file has different number of unused ports then the substring I used didn't work.

Comment: Try the following regex to obtain all matches: `(?sm)(?<=^999.*?)Fa\S*`

Comment: that would give me same result as using '(?sm)(?=^999.*?(?=\r?\n\S|\Z)'. I am looking for better way than using substring to extract just the unused ports number dynamically based on different config files which may have different number of unused ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pragmatic solution that uses the unary form of PowerShell's `-split` operator:

```
# Get the block of relevant lines as a single string.
$unusedVlan = if ((Get-Content -raw c:\config.txt) -match '(?ms)^999.*?(?=\r?\n\S|\Z)') 
  { $Matches[0]} 

# Split the string into an array of token by whitespace,
# remove all "," instances,
# and skip the first 3 tokens 
# (the tokens *before* the port numbers, namely '999', 'Unused', 'active')
# The result is an *array* of all port numbers: @( 'Fa0/10', 'Fa0/11', ... )
$unusedPorts = (-split $unusedVlan) -replace ',' | Select-Object -Skip 3

# Output the array
$unusedPorts
```

Comment: great, it worked, but if I took the -raw out, and it didn't work.  My issue is I want to get-content and read all the config files in the folder and do select-string to extract the hostname, the version number, etc so if I use -raw then the Select-String did not work.

Comment: @Justin: Glad to hear it. Regarding the remaining issue: I don't fully follow, but I suggest you ask a _new_ question - feel free to ping me here when you have done so.